# How to use a config from pyproject.toml inside pre-commit-config.yaml

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, pyproject.toml

I have a python repository which has a pyproject.toml and a pre-commit-config.yaml

The pyproject.toml looks something like this

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "projectname"
description = "My project's description"
authors = ["My Name <my-name@example.com>"]
version = "0.1.0"
```

Now I want to use the name field from pyproject.toml instead of  in the following custom hook in my pre-commit config

```yaml
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: check-for-utility-imports
        name: check-for-utility-imports
        entry: ^from <PROJECT-NAME-COMES-HERE>.utility.* import
        files: ^<PROJECT-NAME-COMES-HERE>/contracts/.*.py$
        language: pygrep
        types: [ python ]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

the pre-commit configuration itself is entirely static, there is no substitution.  I suspect you're trying to over-DRY and you'd be better to just use the name inline.

that said, you can write a custom script which does what you want (reads the toml file, searches for the particular string in your files)

note you have a microbug in your regex as well, you should be escaping the `.` otherwise it false-positives on `projectname_utilities`

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: I have a bunch of python repositories. And I currently use the same pre-commit-config file for all of them. So, wanted to see if there is a way to keep it that way.